# 'ProgbarLogger' object has no attribute 'log_values'

Tags: python, keras

I am trying to run bgru.py in the following link :
https://github.com/SySeVR/SySeVR/tree/master/Implementation/model

```
I am getting following error:
Train...
(0, 0)
start
Epoch 1/10
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bgru.py", line 220, in <module>
    main(traindataSetPath, testdataSetPath, realtestdataSetPath, weightPath, resultPath, batchSize, maxLen, vectorDim, layers, dropout)
  File "bgru.py", line 85, in main
    model.fit_generator(train_generator, steps_per_epoch=steps_epoch, epochs=10)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1426, in fit_generator
    initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training_generator.py", line 229, in fit_generator
    callbacks.on_epoch_end(epoch, epoch_logs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/callbacks.py", line 77, in on_epoch_end
    callback.on_epoch_end(epoch, logs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/callbacks.py", line 336, in on_epoch_end
    self.progbar.update(self.seen, self.log_values)
AttributeError: 'ProgbarLogger' object has no attribute 'log_values'
```

the version of keras, that i am using is 2.2.0, when i installed 2.3.0 i got this ImportError: cannot import name tf_utils, so i installed the 2.2.0, the number of data files that as giving as input is 999.I am not understanding why this error happens!! I don't know to give a proper solution for this error!!

Comment: How exactly did you install Keras?

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro  I install keras as follows :sudo pip install keras==2.2.0

Comment: Ok, it is not a good idea to run sudo with pip, prefer pip install --user. The problem that produces this error is that your training set is empty.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro ok, let me check!!!

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro Same error is occuring!!